# Is compile time code generation possible for xproj projects?

Tags: c#, compilation, compile-time-weaving

In MSBuild based projects generating code seems easy enough as i have seen from PostSharp, Fody, and my own project.

However i haven't really seen anything yet on how to do this in a xproj file, since i can't hook myself into the build chain through targets.

Am I missing something here, or is it just not possible at the moment? I assume there has to be some way, since MVC 6 also does this somehow?